# How to deploy IIS webApp on actual server (globally)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, server, iis-10

I have an application running on localhost, and I was trying to find a way to upload it on an ACTUAL server so that everyone around the world can use. I know there is a certain process to be followed and that one must purchase the rights for a specific URL but my knowledge in these is limitless.

A bit about the structure of my application:

OS: `Windows 10 Home 1909`

IIS Version: `IIS-10`

DIR: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mymindmapper`

APP-POOL: `Classic .NET AppPool`

Directory-Browsing: `Enabled`

Request Filtering: only `web.config` for now

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts: `127.0.0.1 mymindmapper.com`

*For more information please ask in the comments. Also, I'm going to use* `Visual Studio Code` *to write my code*.

Any tutorial/ forum/ chat/ link would be much appriciated. Many thanks.

Comment: to host the site on the internet you need to bind the public IP and valid purchased domain name without that you could not able to access the site from the internet. after purchasing ip and domain name you need to bind them with iis site.  if possible us iis on server Os. windows 10 is client OS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JalpaPanchal. Do you know anyone that sells those and how to do it?

Comment: you could find so many domain providers eg., Bluehost, HostGator, GoDaddy etc

Comment: Once again thanks. that's the information I wanted to proceed :D

Comment: I posted the comment, if it solves your issue then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as ana answer. it will help other people who face a similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to host the site on the internet you need to bind the public IP and valid purchased domain name without that you could not able to access the site from the internet. after purchasing ip and domain name you need to bind them with iis site. if possible us iis on server Os. windows 10 is client OS.